# How to run a java project with vm arguments from command line?

Tags: java, maven, command, arguments

I'm writing a maven plugin which has to initialize another java project with specific VM arguments. according to the exec:java, they only take in arguments but not VMarguments, so my question is how to launch a java project with specific VMarguments from the command line?
thanks

Comment: You have looked at the exec java plugin of what? In which system does the command line have plugins?

Comment: Judging from the mention of the exec plugin and the OP's previous questions, he probably wants to execute a java program from Maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't supply extra VM arguments if you use Maven's exec:java plugin because it runs in the same VM (i.e. it's already been initialized). You'll need to use exec:exec, and construct the java command line yourself.

Comment: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html has specific instructions